# Ventana modal en full calendar con django

Tags: django, fullcalendar

Buenos días estoy haciendo un calendario donde se listan las citas pero quiero hacer que cuando se le de clic a un evento del calendario se abra una modal con los detalles de esa cita pero no se como conseguir el id de esa cita para ver los detalles

este es mi calendario

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var calendarUI  = document.getElementById("calendar")
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarUI,{
  eventTimeFormat: { 
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
},
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  events: [
    {% for cita in citas %}
    {
      title:"{{cita.titulo}}",
      start: "{{cita.inicio}}",
      end: "{{cita.fin}}",
    },
    {% endfor %}

  ],
  eventClick: function(arg) {
    alert(arg.id_cita)
  },
});
calendar.render();
calendar.setOption('locale','es')
```

});

y esta es mi vista

```
class Calendario(TemplateView,PermissionMixin):
permission_required = ['view_calendario']
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    UserSesion=if_User(request)
    cambiosQueryset = cambios.objects.all()
    cambiosfQueryset = cambiosFooter.objects.all()
    citas=Cita.objects.filter(cliente_id=request.session['pk'])
  
    context={
        "User":UserSesion,
        "citas":citas, 
        'cambios':cambiosQueryset, 
        'footer':cambiosfQueryset
    }
    
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

y este mi modelo

```
class Calendario(models.Model):
#falta el id de este campo importante tambien organizar la parte donde se agendan citas creo
id_calendario = models.AutoField("Id del la cita en el calendario", primary_key=True, unique=True)
empleado_id=models.ForeignKey(usuario, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, db_column="empleado_id", related_name="empleado_calendario_id", blank=False)
cliente_id=models.ForeignKey(usuario, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, db_column="cliente_id",related_name="cliente_calendario_id")
cita_id=models.ForeignKey(Cita, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,db_column="cita_id")
dia=models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
horaInicio=models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
horaFin=models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'calendario'
    verbose_name = 'calendario'
    verbose_name_plural = 'calendario'

def __str__(self):
    return f"el cliente de esta cita es: {self.cliente_id}"

@property
def titulo(self):
    title = f"{str(self.cliente_id.nombres).upper()} {str(self.cliente_id.apellidos).upper()}" 
    return title

@property
def inicio(self):
    start = self.dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    hora = self.horaInicio.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    start = f"{start}T{hora}"
    return start

@property
def fin(self):
    end = self.dia.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    hora = self.horaFin.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    end = f"{end}T{hora}"
    return end
```

Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar es que ya intente de muchas formas pero no se como asignarle a cada evento un id para luego capturarlo, ya se como abrir la modal pero para solo necesito el id para hacer la consulta luego unir un documento externo con javascript dentro de la modal

Comment: David, ¿Qué versión de fullcalendar utilizas? Es que la respuesta puede variar dependiendo de eso. Por ejemplo en la versión 5 la clave sería en esa función `eventClick: function(arg)`, en la que `arg.event` contendría las propiedades del evento tal cual (más `arg.event.extendedProps`, que contendría las propiedades personalizadas que le hayas dado)

Comment: Hola la versión que utilizo es la 5.10.2

Comment: cuando hago esto                                                                                             eventClick: function(arg) {
        alert(arg.event.id_cita)
      },                                                                                                                     me salta undefined

Comment: Hay que utilizar la propiedad `arg.event.id`. También cuando pueblas los eventos. `id_cita` no es una propiedad del objeto event. Las propiedades no típicas (si se alimentan cuando lo creas) irán a extendedProps